# pandas dataframe getting daily data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamps as index:

[image: Original Pandas Dataset]

I would like to convert it to get a dataframe with daily values but without having to resample the original dataframe (no to sum, or average the hourly data). Ideally I would like to get the 24 daily values in a vector for each day, for example:
[image: Goal Pandas Dataset]

Is there a method to do this quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you copy/paste your input and your expected outout within Stackoverflow tools ?

Comment: Sorry @nexus66, what do you mean with Stackoverflow tools?

Comment: Look at the tools when you write your question and use them. Don't post a photos of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @nexus66, I use to use these tools to include code, but I couldn't find any method to upload the dataframe if this is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can `groupby` on the `date` attribute of your index and then apply a lambda that aggregates the values into a list:

```
In [21]:
# generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'GFS_rad':np.random.randn(100), 'GFS_tmp':np.random.randn(100)}, index=pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,1,1), freq='1h', periods=100))
df.groupby(df.index.date)['GFS_rad','GFS_tmp'].agg(lambda x: [x['GFS_rad'].values,x['GFS_tmp'].values])

Out[21]:
                                                      GFS_rad  \
2016-01-01  [-0.324115177542, 1.59297335764, 0.58118555943...   
2016-01-02  [-0.0547016526463, -1.10093451797, -1.55790161...   
2016-01-03  [-0.34751220092, 1.06246918632, 0.181218794826...   
2016-01-04  [0.950977469848, 0.422905080529, 1.98339145764...   
2016-01-05  [-0.405124861624, 0.141470757613, -0.191169333...   

                                                      GFS_tmp  
2016-01-01  [-2.36889710412, -0.557972678049, -1.293544410...  
2016-01-02  [-0.125562429825, -0.018852674365, -0.96735945...  
2016-01-03  [0.802961514703, -1.68049099535, -0.5116769061...  
2016-01-04  [1.35789157665, 1.37583167965, 0.538638510171,...  
2016-01-05  [-0.297611872638, 1.10546853812, -0.8726761667...
```